# Case When SQLPL

Tags: sql, oracle

The Error is missing right parenthesis

```
select
    case when TO_CHAR (current_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'TUE' then
        (select * from CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN 
         where
             PLANNED_DUE_DATE between to_date(current_date +1) and to_date(current_date + 3)
             and customer_no not in ('1000' '2000')
             and state not in( 'Delivered'))
    else 
        (select * from CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
         where
             PLANNED_DUE_DATE  between to_date(current_date - 1) and to_date(current_date + 1)
             and customer_no not in ('1000', '2000')
             and state not in( 'Delivered'))
    end 
from dual
```

The Error is missing right parenthesis.

Comment: The `select *` is going to cause this to fail anyway, so I wouldn't focus on fixing this particular error.  Instead, you should ask a question with an explanation of the logic you want, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: It also looks like you are concatenating the JOIN key word to your table name (i.e. CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN ...  should be CUSTOMER_ORDER JOIN ...)

Comment: @Acroyear: that's probably the name of a view.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You are likely correct. That's a very strange view name

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma here

```
in ('1000' '2000')
```

it should be

```
in ('1000', '2000')
```

---

Because the sub-selects yield a value for a column in the result set, you must select one single column instead of `*`. The `case when` must select a single value. You cannot have it return more than one column.

---

Since both sub-queries select from the same source, I would use a single `select` and put the whole logic into the where-clause. See Justin Cave's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `case` statement that runs one of two `select` statements.  So the basic structure of what you have here won't work.  Is this code in a procedure (or other PL/SQL block) where `current_date` is a local variable?  If so, you potentially want an `IF` statement instead.  Potentially, you just want a single query with an `OR` clause

```
select * 
  from CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
 where ((    TO_CHAR (current_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'TUE' 
         and PLANNED_DUE_DATE  between to_date(current_date + 1)
                                   and to_date(current_date + 3)) 
        OR
        (    TO_CHAR (current_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') != 'TUE' 
         and PLANNED_DUE_DATE  between to_date(current_date - 1)
                                   and to_date(current_date + 1)))
  and customer_no not in ('1000', '2000')
  and state not in( 'Delivered')
```

Although I have not changed it, it is very unlikely that you really want `to_date( current_date + n)` in your code.  Assuming `current_date` is a `date`, calling `to_date` ideally does nothing but potentially causes failures by implicitly casting the `date` to a `varchar2` only to be converted explicitly back to a `date`.  That may fail based on things like a session's NLS settings.  If `current_date` has a non-midnight time component that you are trying to ignore, you realistically want `trunc(current_date) + n` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.